# How can I the change text color of the cells of a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have added some data in UITableView, and I want to change the color of the text displayed in the cells.

Is there a delegate method for doing this, or any other way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add labels in the cell and set the color for these labels according to you .And also you can add more than one label and customize the cell.

simply use this line

```
cellLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor]; //according to you.
```

Comment: There is no need for that. you can do it as I answered down.

Answer (score 37):

NO need for Labels

You just need to code :

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

or if you want to change the detailTextLabel :

```
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

good luck

Comment: In case of more than 2 text on cell then you need to make your label because cell having only textLabel and detailTextlabel

Comment: I agree but that is not what he was asking. you can do by Quartz if you want and in many other ways. I think that you should answer the trivial way and add this option to.

Answer (score 1):

The code according to hex number of color code

Use this code

If color code is: #4B4B4B so Red:75 Green:75 Blue:75

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = 
             [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:75.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```